# Send only Selected array data to another array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have a JSON array with the following data

```
source=[{"OperationName":"All","PrivilegeName":"Roles CRUD"},
        {"OperationName":"Read","PrivilegeName":"Roles Read Delete"},
        {"OperationName":"Delete","PrivilegeName":"Roles Read Delete"},
        {"OperationName":"Read","PrivilegeName":"Roles Update"},
        {"OperationName":"Update","PrivilegeName":"Roles Update"}]
```

I have a destination array i.e. `destination =[];`

I have created a function bindRowEvent() which returns the selected row from a table and saves it to the variable `_currentSelectedRow`.

I'm trying to select the particular row and send only the selected value to the destination array.
I'm able to do this for the first value, but on second call to the function it just overwrites the first value in destination

```
function AssignOne(_currentSelectedRow) {
         debugger;
         //destination.push(_currentSelectedRow);

         if (destination.length == 0) {
              destination = source.slice(_currentSelectedRow, 1);
         }
         else {                                 
              destination = source.slice(_currentSelectedRow, destination.length+1);

         }

         source.splice(_currentSelectedRow, 1);
         console.log(destination);

         displaySource();
         displayDestination2();
         bindRowEvent();
 }
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: destination.push() didn't work?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle from your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, your code will work a bit, but only when `_currentSelectedRow` is `0` the first time you run it. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6hqn7xs5/1/. This is because in the "slice" call you always specify the "end" parameter as 1. [As per the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) this means that the returned array will only contain things *before* index 1. In turn this means if you specify any number higher than 0 for the "begin" parameter then the range given for the slice can't select any items. You'd have to specify "end" dyanmically as always being one greater than "begin".

Secondly, the reason it's overwriting the the whole of destination every time is because the `=` operator reassigns the value of the `destination` variable to the newly given value. It doesn't add things to it. That's a very basic concept of JavaScript (and most programming languages) which you need to make sure you understand.

However, since you only ever want to select one item, the whole thing above is redundant.  It's trivial to select a single item by its index and then add it to the array in the (well-documented) way using [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```js
var source = [{
    "OperationName": "All",
    "PrivilegeName": "Roles CRUD"
  },
  {
    "OperationName": "Read",
    "PrivilegeName": "Roles Read Delete"
  },
  {
    "OperationName": "Delete",
    "PrivilegeName": "Roles Read Delete"
  },
  {
    "OperationName": "Read",
    "PrivilegeName": "Roles Update"
  },
  {
    "OperationName": "Update",
    "PrivilegeName": "Roles Update"
  }
];
var destination = [];

function AssignOne(_currentSelectedRow) {
  destination.push(source[_currentSelectedRow]);

  console.log(destination);

  /*displaySource();
  displayDestination2();
  bindRowEvent();*/
}

AssignOne(0);
AssignOne(2);
```

---

P.S. I would gently suggest that you read up on the basics of [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [JavaScript assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) so you don't make these kind of errors in future.